# Change Frontmotion Firefox config for SSO

Tags: firefox, single-sign-on

I'm trying to change the firefox config `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris;` so I can use SSO for everyone on my companies internal page.

First I found this:
[manage Firefox via group policy](http://eventhisnameistaken.blogspot.de/2012/06/manage-firefox-via-group-policy-easy.html)

I tried this on the  `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris;` but it won't work since this specific config is locked. The pref however is set in the pref.js in the Firefox profile folder but SSO is not working.

I tried to use lockPref in the user.js but it won't work.
I have found no entries containing another `lockPref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris",...)`. Neither in the profile folder nor in the program folder.

Any ideas how to unlock this specific pref? Also it seems like a change of users.js will not change the prefs.js right after the first start of FF. Instead it took me more than 1 restart of FF to see the changes of users.js in the prefs.js.

Comment: Wait, so you're managing the company's intranet & SSO, but aren't allowed to change Firefox preferences? Couldn't you ask the person who set up the pref locks in the first place?

Comment: No! I am a software-developer and for SSO I need FF config to be set. So I found the page which is linked above so I could hopefully set the config for Frontmotion FF and non "normal" FF since both versions are used in our company. On the "normal" FF this works just fine but not on the Frontmotion. My guess is that this config can not be set via user.js for Frontmotion (probably because of the lock). So now I thougt there might be a way to get around this lock.